# Releasing a COM object reference safely from .NET

Tags: .net, com-interop, rcw

I have read a lot of articles on the net about releasing RCW's safely, and it seems to me that no one can agree on exactly what needs to be done in what order, so I'm asking you guys for your opinions. For example, one could do this:

```
object target = null;
try {
    // Instantiate and use the target object.
    // Assume we know what we are doing: the contents of this try block
    // do in fact represent the entire desired lifetime of the COM object,
    // and we are releasing all RCWs in reverse order of acquisition.
} finally {
    if(target != null) {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(target);
        target = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
}
```

However, some people advocate doing the garbage collection before `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject`, some after, and some not at all. Is it really necessary to GC every single RCW manually, especially after it has already been detached from its COM object?

To my mind, it would be simpler and easier to just detach the RCW from the COM object and leave the RCW to expire naturally:

```
object target = null;
try {
    // Same content as above.
} finally {
    if(target != null) {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(target);
    }
}
```

Is it sufficient to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To have your reference to the target COM object released, it is sufficient **and preferred** to just call `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` and **not** force a collect.  In other words, you've met your responsibility to release your reference as soon as you were done with it.  I won't touch the issue of `FinalReleaseComObject` vs `ReleaseComObject`.

This leaves the bigger question of why do people advocate calling `GC.Collect()` and `WaitForPendingFinalizers()`?

Because for some designs, it's hard to know when there are no more managed references so you can't safely call `ReleaseComObject`. You have two choices, let the memory build up and hope a collect happens or force a collect. [see Steven Jansen's note in the comments]

An additional note is that setting `target` to `null` is usually unnecessary, and specifically is unnecessary in your sample code.  Setting objects to nothing is common practice for VB6 since it uses a reference count based garbage collector.  The compiler for C# is clever enough (when building for release) to know that `target` is unreachable after its last use and could be GC'd, even before leaving scope.  And by last use, I mean last possible use so there are cases where you might set it to `null`.  You can see this for yourself with the code below:

```
   using System;
   class GCTest
   {
       ~GCTest() { Console.WriteLine("Finalized"); } 
       static void Main()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("hello");
           GCTest x = new GCTest();
           GC.Collect();
           GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
           Console.WriteLine("bye");
       }
   }
```

If you build release (e.g., CSC GCTest.cs), "Finalized" will print out between "hello" and "bye".  If you build debug (e.g., CSC /debug GCTest.cs), "Finalized" will print out after "bye" whereas setting `x` to null prior to `Collect()` would have "fixed" that.

Comment: Downvote: these people all recommend the opposite in favor of `GC.Collect`:
[a Microsoft Distinguished Engineer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/16/51355.aspx) , [the Visual Studio Team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx) , and [a highly ranked SO member](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/1995977)

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for the links.  I've updated the answer to include a reference to your caveats.

Comment: @SteveJansen - the first two links do *not* advise calling `GC.Collect`. Also the first one says *"We really need to add a ReleaseComObjectFully() service"* - that was later added as `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject`, which is what Tony Lee recommended above. The MS links are concerned with what happens when a COM object is rewritten as a non-COM object, or when it is visible to multiple clients and so clean-up must be managed carefully. These concerns often don't apply.